# Mongoid with Machinist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, machinist

I am using machinist and mongoid. How can I generate blueprint for embeds_many association. Mongoid embeds_many association embeds the hash of array. So I just started like this:

```
 User.blueprint do
   address { :address1 => "address", :address2 => 'next address'}
 end
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is this Ruby code? It looks like it, but I don't actually know Ruby. You should add whatever language this is to the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Just tried in this way and worked

```
User.blueprint do   
 addresses {Address.make} 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
User.blueprint do
   address { [{:address1 => "address"} , {:address2 => 'next address'}]}
end
```